# send mail via php yii until success on time

Tags: php, yii, wait

i have php function that send mail on special time ever 7 days but when i send mail its sometimes not sent because server busy or not available ,my question is how to try send my email many times when its something wrong every 10 minute until its send success

```
    private function sendEMailMessage($args) {
    $failed = true;
    for($i = 0; $i < 5 && $failed; $i ++) {
        $failed = Utilities::sendEMailMessage ( $args ) != '';
        if ($failed) {
            sleep ( 15 );
        }
    }
}
```

//its this work or not ???

Comment: Use cron jobs with database, just make sure you figure out that email did not get to receiver (usually mail send functions responds `success` indicating that email was send, but not guarantee that it's received)

Comment: what about performance is like java make the server busy throw wait() or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The another way you can do this is setting a flag in database table. Based on the flag  value you can send/resend the email. On successful sending of email you can delete or reset the flag .

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this problem would be to set up cron jobs for every 7 days.And for the mail sometimes getting not sent purpose you could use this,

```
    if (Yii::$app->mailer->getTransport()->isStarted()) {
    Yii::$app->mailer->getTransport()->stop();}
    Yii::$app->mailer->getTransport()->start();
```

If this is included in your yii app then once the mail is sent it should clear the ssl socket layer and open a fresh socket again for the next time.With the combined use of these I think it should work.